# How to extract different domains from access.log

Tags: bash, apache, grep, logfile

I want to extract the number of requests for each domain separately. Access.log "apache" - Vhost
To get the following result:

```
# domain10.com  20-11-2020
   560  22:00
   550  22:01
   620  22:02
# test.domain20.com
number request       time
   550              22:01
   620               22:02
```

I use `grep` to extract all requests per hour - minute

```sh
grep "[domain.com]" /root/eslam33/test/access.log.7 |
cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' |
sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 > 10) print $0}'
```

output: from access.log:

```
105.181.206.150 - - [30/Nov/2020:06:37:03 +0200] "POST /store/web/app.php/api/v3/WEB/products/filter?_locale=en_US HTTP/1.1" 200 19002 "https://from-egypt.com/en_US/collection?taxons=Fashion&sort=date&order=asc&page=1"
```

but I want to run one command or script to give each domain requests separately. How can I do that?

Comment: Good that you have sown your efforts in your question. Could you please post sample of apache logs(samples looking wise near to your actual logs) and expected output(with logic of how we will get it) in your question, so that we get a better picture of your question.

Comment: The answer here is auto didacticism.You youngsters give up too soon.

Comment: `grep "[domain.com]"` will extract every line which contains `d` or `o` or `m` or `a` or `i` or `n` or `.` or `c`(or `o` or `m` but we already said that) anywhere.

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: @eslamshehata : What do you mean by _give each domain requests separately_ . Provide an example for the desired output. BTW, your pattern `grep "[domain.com]"` does not make much sense. It matches a single character from the Set 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'o', '.', so it returns any line which contains one of these characters.

Comment: It should not be hard to find [near-duplicate questions with various manipulations of Apache logs with Awk.](/search?q=%5Bawk%5D+apache.log&searchOn=3)

Comment: A single line of example input is a bit hard to extrapolate from. You would like to extract `from-egypt.com` in this example, is that correct?

Comment: @tripleee yes ..  also when run :   grep "[from-egypt.com]" /root/eslam33/test/access.log.7  | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 > 10) print $0}'     ...  give >  grep: Invalid range end
Although there are a number of domains like test-egypt.com  -  test2-egypt.com

Comment: Again, still, because your regex is broken, as already pointed out in two separate comments above. The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag page](/tags/regex/info) has a section about this problem, and various other common beginner errors.

Comment: @eslamshehata: Did these answers below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with awk and a standard apache log file:

```
awk '{ 
        split($4,map1,"[:\/]");
        split($11,map2,"/"); # split to get the domain name
        if (map2[3] == "")
        {
          next
        }
        map[map2[3]" "substr(map1[1],2)" "map1[2]" "map1[3]" "map1[4]":"map1[5]]+=1 
     } 
 END { 
        for (i in map) 
                      { 
                         print i" - "map[i]
        } 
     }' access_log
```

One liner:

```
awk '{ split($4,map1,"[:\/]");split($11,map2,"/");if (map2[3])=="") { next } map[map2[3]" "substr(map1[1],2)" "map1[2]" "map1[3]" "map1[4]":"map1[5]]+=1 } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i]} }' access_log
```

Split the 4th space delimited field using : and / into array called map. Then use the day, month, year, hour and minutes (different indexes of map1) to create an index for another array map. Add the domain name by splitting the 9th field. This array is incremented every time the request is encountered for the same day, month, year, minute and hour. At the end, the data from the array is printed.

In order to search on a specific domain, simple add a pattern match on field 9 and so:

```
awk '$11 ~ /from-egypt\.com/ { 
        split($4,map1,"[:\/]");
        split($11,map2,"/");
        if (map2[3])=="") 
        { 
          next 
        }
        map[substr(map1[1],2)" "map1[2]" "map1[3]" "map1[4]":"map1[5]]+=1 
     } 
 END { 
        for (i in map) 
                      { 
                         print i" - "map[i]
        } 
     }' access_log
```

Comment: I own many domains and supdomains
I want to use a variable that gives me all results for all domains inside

Comment: OK. I've removed the pattern matching at the start of the awk statements.

Comment: when run    awk '{ split($4,map1,"[:\/]");split($9,map2,"/");map[map2[3]" "substr(map1[1],2)" "map1[2]" "map1[3]" "map1[4]":"map1[5]]+=1 } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i]} }' /root/eslam33/test/access.log.6
 give me  .. It doesn't give me results organized hourly and minutes, nor does it indicate the domain name

Comment: Apologies. Should have been processing field 11 and not 9. I have amended. The entries are indexed by domain name/day/month/year/hours/minutes.

Comment: awk '$11  ~ /from-egypt.com/ {  split($4,map1,"[:\/]");split($9,map2,"/");map[map2[3]" "substr(map1[1],2)" "map1[2]" "map1[3]" "map1[4]":"map1[5]]+=1 } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i]} }' access.log.2      ( output  Fromegypt  just) >> brother  I need my brother to give results for all domains

Comment: If you want all domains, leave out the "$11 ~ /from-egypt.com/" at the start.

Comment: awk '{  split($4,map1,"[:\/]");split($9,map2,"/");map[map2[3]" "substr(map1[1],2)" "map1[2]" "map1[3]" "map1[4]":"map1[5]]+=1 } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i]} }' access.log.2
>> Not appear all domains
All requests appear on some of them without indicating the domain name, and the times are not organized, unlike what I worked on from egypt

Comment: I've amended to skip any entries that don't have a domain name,

Comment: I need run :this command  :  awk '{ split($4,map1,"[:\/]");split($9,map2,"/");map[map2[3]" "substr(map1[1],2)" "map1[2]" "map1[3]" "map1[4]":"map1[5]]+=1 } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i]} }'       ...  but need to give domain name and  number of requests   ( like =  domain.com   
 24 Nov 2020 15:29 - 447

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the text in the last quoted field between the second and third slashes, try

```sh
sed 's%.*"https*://\([^/]*\)/[^"]*"$%\1%' apache.log
```

If you want the minute and the hour of the visit as a prefix, that's doable too:

```sh
sed 's%[^[]*\[[^:]*:\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\)\].*"https*://\([^/]*\)/[^"]*"$%\1 \2%' apache.log
```

Your `sort` pipeline should work fine as such; then add a bit of postprocessing to format it to your liking.

```sh
sed 's%[^[]*\[[^:]*:\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\)\].*"https*://\([^/]*\)/[^"]*"$%\1 \2%' apache.log |
sort -n | uniq -c |
awk 'NR == 1 || $2 != prev { print "# " $2; prev = $1; next }
   $1 > 10 { print $1, $3 }'
```

Comment: where write domain name ??

Comment: This simply extracts them all. If you want just one, update the regex after `https://\(` up to `\)` to the one you want. And don't put any square brackets where they don't belong, okay?